# My terminal does not display characters anymore

Tags: terminal, character

Since this morning I cannot use my termnial...

As you can see above it does not display any character correctly and is totally useless :

[image: screenshot]

Do you have an idea on how to fix it ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was related to the gnome terminal, I removed it and now use QTerminal which works great !